# SQLite: querying partitioned tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 100 tables with >1M records in each. All tables differ by names but have identical structure:

```
 (valueX INT NOT NULL, valueY INT NOY NULL, valueZ INT NOT NULL).
```

All table names are listed in separate table `NAMES(name TEXT NOT NULL)` but due to SQLite limitations table name cannot be substituted in query as a variable.

I want to search in all tables rows where `valueX > valueZ AND valueZ < valueY` while skipping first N and retrieving next K rows.

I prefer not to waste disk space and/or memory, since I believe they may be not enough. That's effectively eliminates the *UNION* option I guess.

What can be done - considering the constraints?

PS. By "What can be done" I express my will to learn about proper strategy and to see a sample of relevant query.

PPS. Number of tables can change anytime.

Comment: Table per date/customer is not partitioning. [SELECT * FROM sales + @yymm](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm)

Comment: this comment is not helpful.

Comment: Of course it is helpful (ideas not ready to use solution). It is about SQL Server but in general you could: 1) build dynamic query in application 2) use prepared statement in SQLite (I am not sure if it support it) 3) Wrap your tables with view. Anyway your design is flawed

Comment: Why it is flawed anyway?

Comment: Table per ... is common antipattern.

Comment: Why do you think I implement "table per..." antipattern?

Comment: `I have 100 tables with >1M records in each. **All tables differ by names but have identical structure**:`

Comment: Please try not to jump to conclusions regarding my goals, designs and rest of unknowns. All relevant details are written in question body, if something is missing I will publish by request or without it.

Comment: I am not jumping to conclusion, your description is very clear and there is nothing to add. I also provided 3 approaches (I guess building dynamic query based on your metadata table would suit you best). Now it is all up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite will do [subquery flattening](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#subquery_flattening), if possible, so there is no disk/memory penalty for simply combining the tables with `UNION ALL` (preferrably in a view) and doing a query on that.